# Reactive Form name unique validator

Tags: angular

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6 and I'm using Reactive Form. I have a `name` field that I want to validate if it's unique or not. I'm comparing its value with an array.

```
companies: Company[];

this.companyFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      emailAddress: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])]
    }, {validator: this.uniqueValidator});

uniqueValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    const name = control.get('name').value;

    if (control.get('name').valid) {
      const isNameUnique = this.companies.map(company => company.name).some(value => value === name);

      if (!isNameUnique) {
        console.log(isNameUnique);
        control.get('name').setErrors({unavailable: true});
      }
    }
  }
```

> Cannot read property 'companies' of undefined
>       at push../src/app/modules/create-company/create-company.component.ts.CreateCompanyComponent.uniqueValidator
>   (create-company.component.ts:79)
>       at forms.js:602
>       at Array.map ()
>       at _executeValidators (forms.js:602)
>       at FormGroup.validator (forms.js:567)

My goal is to present an error if the name that the user has entered already exists and remove the error if the name is unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the context in your validator method when called from within the FormControl/FormBuilder is not referencing your current component. This is the reason why `this` will be undefined.

You fix this by using `bind` to bind `this` to the validator in order to set the context:

```
validator: this.uniqueValidator.bind(this)
```

You can test it by printing `this` before and after the applying of bind:

```
uniqueValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    const name = control.get('name').value;
    console.log(this)
     /*
    if (control.get('name').valid) {
      const isNameUnique = this.companies.map(company => company.name).some(value => value === name);

      if (!isNameUnique) {
        console.log(isNameUnique);
        control.get('name').setErrors({unavailable: true});
      }
    }*/
  }
```

Comment: If so then it should have given error for like this.uniquevalidator is not defined @wentjun ??